How to down size the storage of AWS RDS MySQL instance?
I have an RDS MySQL instance db.m5.4xlarge with 8.3TB of data, and I want to shrink it to 4TB to save costs because it actually has 4TB of data. What are the viable options?
I've tried several methods, aiming to complete it within 8 hours:

DMS (Database Migration Service):
When using DMS, there were index issues. Before the migration, adding indexes caused it to report duplicate IDs, but I checked and couldn't find any duplicates. After the migration, if I add the indexes back, the data doesn't sync.

Mysqldump:
It takes too long. For 450GB, it's already taking nearly 6 hours.

Take Snapshot and restore to smaller storage:
but the options on AWS console restrict me to downsize to a volume that is smaller than its original sizeenter image description here



Storage is about 8c/GB/month, so 4TB would cost 4000 x .08 = $320/month. That's a significant saving you could achieve! However, it does appear to require a lot of effort. You seem to be following the AWS advice to Decrease the storage size of an Amazon RDS DB Instance | AWS re:Post by using mysqldump. Perhaps can can schedule the export to take place overnight and use a weekend for the full migration?

You might want to compare the cost saving against the cost of downtime and the cost of your time. While it could save $3840 per year, what will be the cost of your effort to make it happen and, more importantly, the impact on users of the system if something goes wrong (eg the indexes and IDs you mentioned). It might be wiser to leave the system as-is rather than make changes that will simply save money without making the system any 'better'. That is for your organisation to decide.

Another option: Have you considered Migrating from RDS MySQL to Aurora MySQL? Running an Amazon RDS MySQL Aurora database will improve performance and will avoid the types of problems you are currently experiencing with storage.

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the largest table (from SHOW TABLE STATUS) .  Maybe we can discuss it in detail.  Also, is this data a time series?  If so, we can discuss summarization and purging.

Just to make sure I understand -- you have 8.3Tb of disk storage provisioned on your RDS instance, but have confirmed that the amount of data you have used is only around 4Tb, so you are trying to move to an instance with smaller storage to reduce storage costs?
As you've found, classic RDS instances don't directly support reducing storage volume size, and don't support using backup and restore to restore to a smaller volume size. (Even if that worked, you'd have to take an outage during the full restore process to avoid data loss; RDS restore will not include transactions from after the time of the snapshot, or the LatestRestorableTime used to start the restore process in case of PointInTimeRestore.)
Have you considered migrating to an RDS Aurora cluster instead? Aurora clusters charge based on used storage instead of provisioned storage, and the migration process is well documented here.
If Aurora is not suitable for your use case, I think your best bet would be to understand and resolve the index errors you are getting with DMS in order to get that solution to work.

yes my RDS is using 8.3Tb of disk storage and it only used 4TB
i want to use MySQL engine to hold my RDS

General steps to reduce DB footprint:

Ensure you have used proper data types for each field. Datetime stored in VARCHAR(255) in utf8mb4 need ~20 bytes while native DATETIME is only 3 bytes long.
Remove unused indexes.
Move from MyISAM/ARIA to InnoDB to avoid sparse files.
Normalize where possible
Use integers as keys for indexing, and avoid indexing by varchars if possible

